# Clicking 'cancel' in confirm() method has the same result as clicking 'ok'

Tags: javascript, html, confirm

I am a beginner implementing a confirm method in my HTML code - when the user clicks on "x", they will be redirected to the home page. Otherwise, nothing happens.

My problem is that in `confirm()`, both "ok" and "cancel" options redirect to home page and I cannot figure out why.

I saw that many people have a similar problem, checked many forums and noticed that writing `onclick="return confirmCancel()` rather than `onclick="confirmCancel()"` helped in most of the cases but it did not solve the problem for me.

HTML:

```
<a onclick="return confirmCancel()"><img src="assets/cancel.svg"></a>
```

JS:

```
const confirmCancel = () => {
    confirm("All your progress will be lost. Are you sure you want to leave?");
    if (confirmCancel) {
        window.location.assign("index.html");
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `confirm()` is a function that returns true if OK is clicked and false if Cancel is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test the return value of `confirm` (rather than the truthiness of the `confirmCancel` function).

```
const confirmCancel = () => {
    if (confirm("All your progress will be lost. Are you sure you want to leave?");) {
        window.location.assign("index.html");
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
<a onclick="pleaseConfirm"><img src="assets/cancel.svg"></a>
```

```js
const pleaseConfirm = () => {
  if (confirm("All your progress will be lost. Are you sure you want to leave?")) {
    window.location.assign("index.html");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mostly there .. You need to check if `confirm()` is true ..  Change:

```
confirm("All your progress will be lost. Are you sure you want to leave?");
    if (confirmCancel)
```

To

```
var test_confirm = confirm("All your progress will be lost. Are you sure you want to leave?");
    if (test_confirm === true)
```

Shorthand can be

```
 if (confirm("All ... ... "){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the functionality inside JavaScript instead of calling out JavaScript function in your HTML tag

```
<a id="btn-exit"><img src="assets/cancel.svg"></a>

var btnExit = document.querySelector('#btn-exit')
btnExit.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (confirm("are you sure?")) {
    window.location.assign("index.html");
  }
})
```